# In OL3 can I adjust the georeferencing of layers I source from elsewhere

Tags: openlayers, georeferencing

I have an OL3 application that works well, and I can source raster maps from many sources. They are already georeferenced by their suppliers and work well in general. However my application is aimed at the **very** local level and some of the rasters are different by a few metres.

You can see the effect in [this example](http://mapping4ops.org/ShowMaps/M4OPS-index.html?OPS=HcN&Layer0=Bing%20Aerial&Layer1=OS%2025%20inch%201924&Zoom=19&Lon=-0.0329857&Lat=52.3290809) where the Bing Aerial layer is about 3 metres north of a 25 inch Ordnance Survey map (use the slider on the left to compare the layers - the roads and many of the buildings have not changed on the ground between 1924 and now, but the layers do not align exactly). I am using the maps to explore how buildings have changed over the years, so need extreme accuracy. I do not need to cover a wide area (just my village) so my idea is that I could supply an 'x/y adjustment factor' that would make the layers exactly match for this locality.

I cannot see anything like this in the OL3 documentation. I do not want to have to re-do any georeferencing, and in many cases (eg Bing Aerial) I cannot.

On the other hand, if the issue I am facing is caused by factors that I am less familiar with (eg projections?) then I will probably need some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can define a custom projection to make the corrections.  OpenLayers can use proj4js v2.2+ for defining your own projections.

See: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html

Assuming the web service maps such as Bing use the Web Mercator projection (3857), your custom projection should use that as the starting point.

```
Proj4js.defs["SR-ORG:6864"] = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
```

From: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/proj4js/

I haven't tested this, but I would try to play around with those projection parameters. This is missing the +lat_0 parameter, which is the "Latitude of origin". So for your example, I would first try to use `+lat_0 = -3` on the Bing layer, or `+lat_0 = -3` on the Ordnance layer.

Parameters for proj4: http://proj4.org/parameters.html#parameter-list

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this clue. I have managed to implement something that works quite well, so I document it below, even though it may not be the best way. Note that my application internally uses EPSG:3857.

In essence I define a new projection (proj3857D - D for Delta) that is an exact copy of EPSG:3857 but simply shifted by a few metres. Rather than the suggested use of lat_0 and lat_0 I decided to use the CoordinateTransform functions to implement the shift. Hence:

```
var proj4Def3857 = "+proj=merc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "; // From http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/
proj4.defs("proj3857D", proj4Def3857);
ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:3857', "proj3857D",
    function(coordinate) {
        return [coordinate[0] - 2.4, coordinate[1] - 5.5];},
    function(coordinate) {
        return [coordinate[0] + 2.4, coordinate[1] + 5.5];});

var projection3857 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'); // The default
var extent3857 = projection3857.getExtent();
// For the shifted projection
var projection = ol.proj.get("proj3857D"); 
projection.setExtent(extent3857); // extent is needed to enable reprojection
```

Above was my solution for a single fixed shifted projection. I also implemented a way of calculating the shifts I needed via a single vector LineString.

However I did want a solution for an unlimited number of possible shifts, specified via a simple csv data file. That was more complicated, especially as the transform functions needed to be carefully constructed. I might have been better sticking with adjusting the lat_0 and lon_0 rather than the transform functions. In case anyone is interested below is what I found worked.

Note that my application has
- an input data file specifying layers in simple csv format
- a PHP generator program that generates a JSON file from the csv specifying the layers more completely
- a javascript program that uses the JSON input to generate the OL3 calls when a layer is needed

Here is what I have done:

1) For each layer that I wish to shift slightly I have specified 2 shift values in the csv input data file: shiftEastM and shiftNorthM - being the metres by which I wish to shift the layer.

2) In my PHP generator program I identify any layers that have non-zero  shift values and:

- assign its source a unique projection name (identified in JSON as eg
  "proj3857D":"proj3857_0")
- include in the JSON file the specification
  of this projection ie its projName, shiftEastM, shiftNorthM

3) In my JS program, when I first load the JSON file I use the specification of each projection to add it to the known projections:

```
// Each LayerDef can have a different projection, as each can be shifted per [shiftEastM;shiftNorthM]
// These are based on EPSG:3857 (= SR-ORG:6864), so we set what is needed here
var proj4Def3857 = "+proj=merc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "; // From http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/

function fCoordTrans(shiftEastM, shiftNorthM, strSign) {
    var str = 'return [';
    str += 'coordinate[0] ' + strSign ;
    str += ' (' + shiftEastM + ')'; // Brackets as shiftEastM can be negative
    str += ', coordinate[1] ' + strSign ;
    str += ' (' + shiftNorthM + ')]';
    return str;
} 

// Define each shifted projection we need
var projections = OPSDetails.ProjectionsArray;
if (projections) {
    for (i=0; i< projections.length; i++) {
        proj4.defs(projections[i].projName, proj4Def3857); // They all start identical to EPSG:3857 
        // We need to create the transform functions as strings 
        //  with the only variable being the coordinate parameter
        //  as otherwise the projections get their scope confused
        var fCoordinateTransformForward = new Function('coordinate', fCoordTrans(projections[i].shiftEastM, projections[i].shiftNorthM, '-'));
        // The Backward function is the same except with pluses instead of minuses
        var fCoordinateTransformBackward = new Function('coordinate', fCoordTrans(projections[i].shiftEastM, projections[i].shiftNorthM, '+'));
        // The transform function is where the shifting is implemented
        ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:3857', projections[i].projName, fCoordinateTransformForward, fCoordinateTransformBackward);           
    }
}
```

4) When a layer is needed I pick up the appropriate projection (sdef here is the source definition):

```
    var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'); // The default
    // We need to set the extent of each projection, else the transforms do not work properly,
    //  so we will just setExtent them equal to this, the default (for EPSG:3857)
    var extent3857 = projection.getExtent();

    if (sdef.proj3857D) { // We need a shifted projection
        projection = ol.proj.get(sdef.proj3857D); // It will already have been defined
        // extent is needed to enable reprojection - see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html        
        projection.setExtent(extent3857);
    }

    sourceToReturn = new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: url,
        projection: projection,
        attributions: atts,
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom
    })
```